# Plain text field - apostrophes are getting escaped

Tags: field, escaping

I have a plain text field in Craft and the content has an apostrophe. On the front end, the apostrophe gets turned into `&#039;`

Not ideal! Thanks in advance..

Comment: You maybe ran into [the same issue as this user](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1632/125)?! Hope this helps.

Comment: I had tried what the answers in that link suggested, but I was just doing it on the wrong element. Oops! That solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see this happening is if the field was originally a Rich Text Field, the content was entered, then the field type was swapped to a plain text field.

If that's the case, the Rich Text Field would have encoded the entities and saved them into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. I just had to do `entry.title|raw`

I had tried this before, but silly me had done it to the wrong heading, so I never saw it change! :D